# Why are my atomic operations occurring in an unexpected order?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, atomic

I don't understand why this is occurring. Take the following piece of psuedo code:

```
volatile unsigned long count = 0;
volatile unsigned long sum = 0;

void ThreadFunction() {
    InterlockedIncrement(&count);
    InterlockedExchangeAdd(&sum, rand());
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // This is the problematic instruction
        InterlockedExchange(&count, 0);
        InterlockedExchange(&sum, 0);

        std::vector<boost::thread> threads(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            threads[j] = boost::thread(ThreadFunction);

        while (count != i)
            Sleep(0);
    }
}
```

On the very first run of the program, when `i = 0`, the atomic exchange on `sum` from the main thread usually occurs **after** the spawned thread has completed. The operations on `count` always occur in the correct order.

This only happens once; it does the operations in the correct order for the remainder of the loop. It doesn't always happen, but it usually does. If I break into the debugger or sleep before the atomic add, the instructions will be carried out in the correct order.

Either way, the result is that the value written by the thread is replaced by the 0 that should have occurred before the thread was even launched.

Why is this happening? Why can't I rely on the processor to complete the atomic instructions I gave it in the order I gave them in? Doesn't an atomic operation imply a memory barrier to prevent reordering?

Side note, this is occurring with Visual Studio 2010. I don't have other versions to test with.

Comment: I doubt this is your problem, but `count` and `sum` variables should also be annotated as `__align(32)` as per the remarks in the documentation for [`InterlockedIncrement()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614(v=vs.85).aspx): "The variable pointed to by the Addend parameter must be aligned on a 32-bit boundary; otherwise, this function will behave unpredictably on multiprocessor x86 systems and any non-x86 systems."

Comment: "when i = 0, the atomic exchange on sum from the main thread usually occurs after the spawned thread has completed" - when `i == 0` no thread is spawned - `j < i` is never true.

Comment: This code is just meant to show what I'm doing, it's not meant to compile. My variables are all 32-bit aligned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An atomic operation is atomic in the sense that it's non-interruptable. It will either not execute or fully complete without another thread getting a look-in.

It does not mean that twenty atomic operations will always occur in the same order, that's still subject to the vagaries of multi-threading.

Depending on how fast your threads start up, they may be sequenced as `main, thrd1, main, thrd2, main, thrd3, ...` or `main, main, main, main, thrd1, main, main, thrd2, ...` or any other combination (though I'm pretty certain `main` would always be first simply because its atomic operation is before starting any threads).

Comment: I just realized I ordered the atomic operations incorrectly. My bad, thanks. I should be incrementing *after* the add.